# Android - item in LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES not being built

Tags: android, android-source

I'm having trouble getting the dependency module to build while building a static library in AOSP. Call this library A, it has a dependency on another static lib B.

A's `Android.mk` looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := A
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <files...>

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := B

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Individually B builds fine (`mma`).

Problem is when I build A, B is not being built. Instead I see this at output:

```
Export includes file: <...>/B/Android.mk -- out/<...>/STATIC_LIBRARIES/B_intermediates/export_includes
```

Can someone explain what does this line mean and, why is it not trying use B's `Android.mk` to properly build B?

I understand it's not ideal to package a static lib inside another, but here I'm more courious about why is it the build system not running through B's makefile, when it's clearly a dependency?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build system ignores lots of irrelevant statements, `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` being one of examples. They don't write every entry in `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` as a dependency for `libA.a`. Instead, they interpret the **Android.mk** files to produce **make** rules for all targets, and if a dependency happens to show up, it will eventually get built, too.

Therefore, the easiest workaround for you would be to add a dummy shared library to your **Android.mk**, like

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := A
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <files...>

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := dummyA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := dummy.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := B

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am not sure if you can drop `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` completely. In terms of good old plain make files, the above is roughly equivalent to:

```
all: libA.a libdummyA.so

libdummyA.so: dummy.c libB.a
gcc -o $@ dummy.c -lb
```

Alternatively, you can manually specify the dependency:

```
$(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libA_intermediates/libA.a: $(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libB_intermediates/libB.a
```

Re: **export_includes** message, it is the result of processing `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` statement for libB.

Comment: Oh my goodness this explains a lot.. Is it specific to this static lib depending on static lib scenario? (If I build a shared lib instead, with one of the dependencies being static lib, the latter is actually going to be built.)

Comment: Sure, as you see above in the case of `dummyA.so`, this will make the static library a *dependency* in **make** sense.